# Division & Modulo Operator

Tags: python, python-2.x, division, modulo, modulus

I just started learning how to code, and I've been assigned a problem that I've been stuck on for many hours now and was hoping I could receive some hints at the very least to solve the problem. The main point of this exercise is to practice division and modulus. We can use basic statements,  but nothing fancy like conditionals or anything since we haven't gotten to that point.

I need a user to input a # from 1 - 25, and then my program will let them know which unit and row that number is in. I've managed to get the code working for the rows, but I cannot figure out how to get the unit number.

Here's my code:

```
shelfNumber = int(raw_input('What is the shelf number? '))
row = int(shelfNumber / 5.1) + 1
unit =
```

I've tried a lot of things for unit, but none of them worked out, so I left it blank. I would appreciate any hints that anyone can give me. Thank you for any help.

[image]

Edit: I realized that I should try and at least show which ideas I've tried. If I do a regular modulo with # % 5, that works for everything but the multiples of 5 all the way on the right. I've also tried implementing the row #'s each # has but haven't gotten anywhere with that either. I've also tried something similar by dividing by a decimal, casting it as an int, then using modulo but failed, etc., etc.\

**Edit:** Sorry, I realized I uploaded the wrong image.

Comment: EM just use this MODULO xD 
**unit = shelfNumber % 5** 
Why ? Because Your rows got 5 items so every item divided with no rest by 5 got 0 units, these with rest 1 got 1 unit and etc ...

Comment: But the ones that are multiples of 5 have to be in unit 5, not unit 0. Edit: Sorry, I uploaded the wrong image!

Comment: But if I do that, all of the other ones will have the wrong units. Like 1 has to be in unit 1. (1 % 5) + 5 would make it 6, not 1.

Comment: Sorry? Is the picture unclear? All of the values have a row # and unit # they are in. 1, 6, 11, 16, and 21 are in unit #1; 2, 7, 12, 17, and 22 are in unit #22, etc.

Comment: unit = (shelfNumber % 6)  xD did typo in my previous answer sorry

Comment: For 25, if I do (25 % 6) + 1, don't I get 2 instead of 5 though?

Comment: final answer is **unit =shelfNumber%5 or shelfNumber%6**
And how it works ? hmmm if shelfNumber will result in 0 there is returned number from shelfNumber%6 it works xD but **or** operator is conditional

Answer (score 1):

This problem would be easier if everything were countrd from 0 instead of from 1. That is, if the row and unit numbers were 0 to 4 instead of 1 to 5 and if the input value were 0 to 24 instead of 1 to 25.

In that case, we'd just write:

```
row = shelfNumber / 5
unit = shelfNumber % 5
```

Since everything starts ftom 1 ("is one-indexed" in the usual jargon), `shelfNumber` is one bigger than what that formula needs, and we need to make `row` and `unit` one bigger than what we computed.

But there's no trouble fixing that:

```
row = (shelfNumber - 1) / 5 + 1
unit = (shelfNumber - 1) % 5 + 1
```

In Python 3, you'd need to write `//` insted of `/`, and that will work with a reasonably recent Python 2.

Comment: Although the OP probably isn't allowed to use it it might be worth mentioning the `divmod` builtin

Comment: @ninja: maybe. But it obscures the math without providing any functional advantage, and `row, unit = map(lambda a:a+1, divmod(shelfUnit - 1, 5))` invites the accusation of obfuscation, if it even works.